# How to draw astrology shape with c#

Tags: c#, graphics

I want to draw the following shape:

[image]

It's okay in drawing circle and radius line withing circle but I want to know if there is specific and formal way (formula) to draw this shape.

Comment: you mean Aquarius.draw() doesn't work for you?

Comment: I've voted to close because you've made no attempt to show us what you've already tried. Plz give us teh codez.

Comment: I don't know this method. Please tell me which dll is needed to import

Comment: This method will reside in your `App_Code` folder **AFTER** you write it. Please post the code you've already tried, or show us how far you've already gotten.

Answer (score 4):

You would draw it the same way you drew it in paint. There is no "Algorithm" for that shape, it is just a process of drawing the circle then the 8 lines in their correct positions. If you need help drawing the circle or lines please ask another question specific to the problem you are having with drawing.

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, some pseudo code for you

1. Draw 6 squares
2. For the corner squares, Draw diagonal lines, from corner to corner, in the appropriate direction according to your picture
3. Draw centered circle around the squares, intersecting with the corner squares.
4. Clear out any pixels outside of the circle

If you need help on the System.Drawing namespace, search (or ask) those questions on this site.